# How to select a specific view from SharePoint Online list on PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, datatable, powerapps

In SharePoint I have a list of orders. There are a lot of columns, but the limit to LookUp is limited. I want to show just a few columns in a DataTable. How can I select a view that only has a few columns?
Even if I can't select a view, how can I solve it?

Thanks for your time!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LySwf.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible right now.
There is a feature request [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/View-in-PowerApps-based-on-sharepoint-list-view/idi-p/168766).

However, there is a hacky workaround. You can filter your desired columns in power automate and use that as a data source in power apps. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4pPCDXoL7c) is a video tutorial about it *(Not my video)*.

Comment: You are my hero! But I have another problem, because that video shows how to do it with SQL, so how can I do it with SharePoint? I've been trying for hours...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ShowColumns()` or `DropColumns()`.

**Example:**

```
ClearCollect(colData,
    ShowColumns(
        BIG_SHAREPOINT_LIST,
        column1,
        column2,
        column3
    )
)
```

Then ONLY columns 1, 2, 3 will appear in the Collection. Easy.